# How to erase ark in Graphics in CodenameOne

Tags: graphics, custom-component, codenameone

I need to delete arc in another arc (to be transparent), but can't find function for this operation

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One doesn't have an erase draw mode but you can just draw an arc to begin with. You can also use image masking if that's what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Masking reference: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/round-at-codemotion

Graphics shape API reference:

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-graphics

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-graphics-part-2-drawing-an-analog-clock

Comment: Not so much. Erasing is REALLY expensive and is hard (not sure its even possible) to hardware accelerate. You should rethink your logic to generate the right circle to begin with which will be far more performant. I suggest you rephrase your question as "what you are actually trying to achieve" and we can see how that can be accomplished without erasing.

Comment: Yes. My task can be solved without erasing, but this is will entail a lot of calculations and excess code

Comment: Depending on what you are doing you might be able to do erasure with Images by drawing on top of mutable images and then using something like an image mask. This will perform badly but erasures would always perform badly, I'm assuming that this isn't something you need for immediate rendering.